# Android Studio 3.4.1 Build Exception in Map Sample

Tags: android, google-maps, android-geofence

I have recently updated my Android studio to 3.4.1. I am planning to integrate Geofencing Application. So I have downloaded the Map Application from the Google sample git repository and import it to new Android studio. But I am getting the below error continuously while building the application.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub$Proxy found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$1 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyRunnable found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)

  Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 18s
16 actionable tasks: 12 executed, 4 up-to-date
```

Comment: You are using a mix of AndroidX and the Support Library, which will not work.

Comment: Make sure you have `android.useAndroidX=true` and `android.enableJetifier=true` in `gradle.properties` and clean and re-sync gradle.

Comment: Can you please tell how we can solve this issue? Because it is automatically added Gradle support for Android x.